# Mouse click does random number of clicks

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I’ve been having a problem with my mouse since last fall, and it’s getting worse.  When I left-click on the mouse, about a third of the time it does what it’s supposed to.  Occasionally, it does nothing.  Mostly, though, it does a double-click, and sometimes a triple-click.

The computer is a 4-5-year old Gateway running Windows 7 64-bitwith 8GB RAM and dual Intel Core i5-2320 CPUs @3.00Hz.

The mouse is wireless, so my first thought was that the batteries were going dead.  Replacing them didn’t help.  I switched to a spare wired mouse that I had lying around; same problem.  I have tried both mice on pretty much every USB port I have.  I have uninstalled the mouse drivers and rebooted to force a re-install.

I tried running `sfc –scannow`; it showed no problems.

Everything else I use in my USB ports works with no problems: keyboard, flash drives, MP3 player, smart phone, tablet, etc.

Does anybody have any idea what could cause this, and/or what I can do about it (short of buying a new computer)?  I’ve even considered upgrading to Windows 10 to see if that solves the problem, but would be a last resort.

PS. Here's another issue that I forgot to include above: when I have managed to click and hold on something to drag it somewhere else, it will often release the object without me moving my finger off the mouse button. Or if I try to click and drag something, the actual click might not happen until after I've started moving the mouse, and I end up dragging something other than my intended target.

Comment: Had a similar issue before but I just replaced the mouse and that did the trick. But you already tried a second mouse so that shouldn't be it. Have you tried adjusting the mouse click speed in control panel? Maybe it's set too sensitive so it causes double clicks. I don't believe that to be the culprit, but it's worth eliminating the possibility. Also, have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the mouse drivers?

Comment: I have not tried changing the mouse click speed.  I have been using the same mouse for years, and it just started happening fairly recently.  nobody else uses this computer, so nobody would have reset it.  Plus, that wouldn't explain why sometimes it does nothing when I click.  And, as mentioned above, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the mouse drivers.

Comment: As I have said twice now, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the mouse drivers.  Multiple times, in fact.  Made no difference.

Comment: First of all, you can localize the problem. Is it software or hardware? Is it specific to environment (EMI and stuff)?

Comment: Also note that when you "delete" a device, the drivers aren't actually uninstalled, the device is just marked "disconnected". Use `devcon.exe` to really delete the device. I never tried that for a mouse though - it uses a "one size fits all" driver due to extremily high standardization among mice so cannot say if it can be deleted even like that.

Comment: Try a live linux system (i.e. From usb or cd/dvd), ubuntu will do. This is to rule out software. If it also happens in linux you have a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, John Keates.  I'll give that a shot as soon as I can.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but you know, holidays and such.  Anyway, finally booted into linux from a USB stick, and still have the same problems with the mouse.  So it must be a hardware problem, right?  Given that it's not the mouse (unless I just happen to have stumbled across multiple mice with the exact same issue), then what?  The usb ports?  They work for everything else.  What else could it be?

Comment: Is your computer a laptop and does it have a touchpad ? Does this happen when all possible devices are disconnected ?

Comment: I wonder if it's power related... Also put the mouse into another machine, does issue persist.

Comment: @harrymc - no, it's not a laptop, it's a desktop, and there's no touchpad.  Generally the only devices connected are the essentials: mouse, keyboard, and monitors.

Comment: @Dave - I have not tried the mouse in another PC, but I have tried multiple mice in this PC, and all have the same problem.  Therefore, the odds of it being a mouse problem are pretty slim.

Comment: Does this happen when you boot into Safe mode? Check for strange setting in Control Panel / Mouse (especially mouse double click speed).

Comment: See also [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/271785/mouse-problems-clicking-in-windows-7). Do you have optional Windows Updates that are not installed and may pertain?

Comment: That's a really strange issue... If you want, you can use Linux to narrow down the problem a bit: Do `ls /dev/input/by-id/`, there should be a file called `usb-...-event-mouse`. Run `evtest` on it as root, e.g. `evtest /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Mouse-event-mouse` for my mouse. Include output when the glitch happens. This will show if there are any spurious events injected by USB HID (or whatever). But this is a shot in the dark, I've no theory what could be wrong.

Comment: Well, here's the final word on this issue: despite the probabilities against multiple mice behaving in the same manner, it was apparently the mouse after all.  I was rummaging through a box of stuff, don't even remember what I was looking for, but I found one of those cheap Dell mice that comes with a new computer but nobody every uses. It was never used, so I plugged it in just to see what would happen.  Voila!  Then I borrowed another wireless mouse from a coworker, and it worked perfectly, too.  So today I went to Best Buy and bought a new wireless Logitech mouse, and my problems are gone.

Comment: So, too all those people who said that the mouse was the problem, and I repeatedly pointed out why it couldn't be the mouse, my apologies.  You were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that it is the USB ports on the motherboard. We had a similar problem with a particular set of Dells at work. I put in multi-port add-on USB cards in them and problem was solved. the cards were only a few bucks each.

Comment: I will check into that next week.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I feel like this is the answer most likely to solve my problem, except I might have bigger problems.  I did install an add-on USB card, but then it immediately starting reporting power surges on the USB hub, saying that "a USB device has exceeded the power limits of its hub port".

At this point, I'm about ready to give up and live with it until I can afford a new computer.

Comment: @AndyDan no need for an entire computer. The problem is with MB so replacing just the MB should do it. Power unit can also be the culprit if it doesn't provide adequate power.

Comment: Well, I was able to resolve the power issue (I failed to connect the power cord to the new card), but that didn't resolve the mouse issue.

Answer (score -3):

I haven't had exactly this problem but I have a whole collection of mice around here that are prone to producing extra clicks when clicked.  Replace the sick rodent, everything's fine.  The problem is mechanical, the switch is wearing out.

Comment: As noted in the original post, I tried multiple mice and had the same behavior from all of them.  Hard to believe they would all wear out at the same time and in the same way.

Answer (score -3):

These are all symptoms of the mouse hardware wearing out. this happens eventually to nearly all mouses, though some hold out better than others; if you want one that will last, some mouses, primarily "gaming" branded, but some others, are rated for some number of clicks, these are generally going to last longer to begin with, but will also allow you to compare them.

when it starts happening to your mouse, you have two choices(or three if you want to count just ignoring it), you can either replace the mouse, or if you want to break out some tools, you can often extend the life of the mouse by opening up, cleaning, and adjusting the contacts for the switch. I don't think this is the exact guide I used when I did this myself so YMMV, but it looks pretty clear: http://www.instructables.com/id/Repair-mouse-with-double-click-problem/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: As noted several times already, multiple mice, only one of which is wireless, exhibit the same symptoms, so probably not a mouse problem.